# Can not push to javascript global array varible

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I'm trying to add data to a global array variable in my ready function. When i later try to use the data my array is empty.

This is my ready function:

```
var counter = 0;
    var services = [];
    var names = []
    var serviceData = []
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $.getJSON(JSurl + "/Home/getServicesForCustomer?name=" + '@Model', function (data) {
            $.each(data, function (index, value) {
                console.log("Trying to push services : " + JSON.parse(value.jsonTEMPLATE).komponent);
                services.push(JSON.parse(value.jsonTEMPLATE).komponent);
                console.log("After push : " + services);
                names.push(value.Name);
                serviceData.push(value.jsonDATA);

            });
        });
        drawKomp(0);
    });
```

This is the function where i want to use my data.

```
function drawKomp(index) {
        console.log("Services in draw" + services);
});
```

This is the log

```
Services in draw NewCustomerWizard?name=Testkund:104
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined jquery-2.0.3.js:564
Trying to push services : [object Object],[object Object] NewCustomerWizard?name=Testkund:90
After push : [object Object],[object Object] NewCustomerWizard?name=Testkund:92
Trying to push services : [object Object],[object Object],[object Object] NewCustomerWizard?name=Testkund:90
After push : [object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object]
```

Why am i getting Cannot read? Seems like my data is added to the services array

Comment: Welcome to the world of asynchronous execution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Bojangles mentioned, this is because your code is executed asynchronously.

When the JS Interpreter reaches the $.getJSON line, the browser sends a request to get the desired data. As soon as the server responds, your callback function gets invoked. But in the meantime, the interpreter reaches drawKomp(0), *before* the server responded.

As the ajax call takes some time, it would be insane if the interpreter would stop execution here. Thats why you provide a callback function.

So code execution looks like this:

```
Send request to JSUrl and remeber function(data){...} to be executed when you got data
call drawKomp(0)
.
.
.
ajax call finished, call function(data){...}
```

So you have to make sure, that drawKomp(0) does not get called before your data is pushed to your array.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to fix this would be:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $.getJSON(JSurl + "/Home/getServicesForCustomer?name=" + '@Model', function (data) {
        $.each(data, function (index, value) {
            console.log("Trying to push services : " + JSON.parse(value.jsonTEMPLATE).komponent);
            services.push(JSON.parse(value.jsonTEMPLATE).komponent);
            console.log("After push : " + services);
            names.push(value.Name);
            serviceData.push(value.jsonDATA);

        });
        drawKomp(0);
    });

});
```

This way, your drawKomp gets executed after the json is loaded and processed.

You can also work with Deferred objects, but that could get complicated.